# In Keyforge, does *Bingle Bangbang* deal the 5 damage when it attacks as well as when it's being attacked?

Tags: keyforge

The card text of [Bingle Bangbang](https://keyforge-compendium.com/sets/2-aoa/cards/2-bingle-bangbang) says:

> Before Fight: Deal 5D to each neighbor of the creature Bingle Bangbang fights.

Because a "fight" happens when [Bingle Bangbang](https://keyforge-compendium.com/sets/2-aoa/cards/2-bingle-bangbang) attacks as well as when it is being attacked, this would mean it deals the 5 damage to the neighbors in both cases. However this appears to me to be a too strong ability, and therefore I wonder whether this is really the case?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**No, Bingle Bangbang's ability will not trigger when it's being attacked.**

---

According to [Keyforge's Rulebook](https://images-cdn.fantasyflightgames.com/filer_public/f9/a2/f9a28865-cd96-4f36-97e5-0f8ea75288c0/keyforge_rulebook_v9-compressed.pdf) (May/2019 version), under **Using Creatures**, the rule **Fight** reads:

> [...] After the fight resolves, if the creature that is being used to fight survives, all “Fight:” abilities the creature has, if it has any, resolve.

While, under **Glossary**, the keyword **Before** is explained:

> If the word “before” is used in an ability (for example, “Before Reap:” or “Before Fight:”), that ability resolves before resolving the game effect of the reap or fight (but after the card exhausts, if exhausting is required to use the card).

As you can see, the rules for **Fight** clearly state that if *the creature being used to fight* survives, all “Fight:” abilities the creature has, if it has any, resolve. Since the ability of Bingle Bangbang is a **Before Fight** trigger, would trigger before the fight resolved, *if it is being used to fight*.

When being *attacked*, creatures' **Fight** ability won't trigger.

Comment: Tangentially, it's worth noting that The Warchest will not count creatures destroyed "Before Fight".